# Filter Managedby Powershell

Tags: powershell, filter, owner

Below are my current attempts to pull AD groups whose managedby equal names like "ML...". I keep getting errors so I wanted to know why I am unable to filter managedby with "-like" when I can filter managedby "-eq $..." variables. I tried making a variable $name = "ML*" so that I can perform {managedby -eq $name} but still had no luck.

I mostly get error like:

```
 Operator(s): The following: ''Eq', 'Ne'' are the only operator(s) suppor
ted for searching on extended attribute: 'ManagedBy'.
```

and so forth because "-eq" is only accepted for some filters I have done. When I use -eq I get these errors:

```
Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type dat
a file: 
Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveD
irectory\ActiveDirectory.Types.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already pres
ent from "Microsoft.PowerShell".
Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveD
irectory\ActiveDirectory.Types.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already pres
ent from "Microsoft.PowerShell".

At J:\\ManagedbyEqualsML.ps1:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  ActiveDirectory
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeExc 
eption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
ands.ImportModuleCommand

The term 'Get-adgroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, scri
pt file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was i
ncluded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At J:\\ManagedbyEqualsML.ps1:53 char:27
+  $MLgroupAll = Get-adgroup <<<<  -Properties managedby, enabled, name -filter 
{managedby -eq $name}
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-adgroup:String) [], CommandN 
otFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here are my codes where I attempted to find Owners that have the name ML*

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$name = "ML*"

#Attempt 1

$MLgroups = Get-adgroup -Properties managedby, enabled, name -filter * | Select name, managedby

foreach ($group in $MLgroups){

if ($group.managedby -like "ML*"){
write-host $group.name + $group.managedby}

}

#Attempt 2

$Mgroups = get-adgroup -Properties name, managedby -filter *
 foreach ($groups in $Mgroups){
        # here get the group name and use the "managedBy attribute to retrieve the user object
        # grou naem
        $gname = $_.Name
        $manager=Get-AdUser $_.ManagedBy
        $MangerName = $manager.DisplayName

        if ($managerName -like "ML*"){
        write-host $gname + $managerName}

}

#Attempt 3

$exportlist = "C:\Temp\managedby.txt"

Clear-Content $exportlist


$Header = `
"Group ID Name" + "|" + "ManagedBy"

$Header | Out-File $exportlist -Append

$list = get-adgroup -properties name, managedby -filter {managedby -like "ML_*"} `
| Select name, managedby | Export-CSV $exportlist -NoType -Delimiter '|'

#Attempt 4

$MLgroupAll = Get-adgroup -Properties managedby, enabled, name -filter {managedby -like $name}
foreach ($group in $MLgroupAll) {

write-host $group.name + $group.managedby}
```

UPDATE: if i try to changed my $name variable it still doesn't work and gives another error.

```
 $MLgroupAll = get-adgroup -Properties managedby, enabled, name -filter {managedby -eq $name}
foreach ($group in $MLgroupAll) {

$managed = $group.managedby
    if ($managed -like "ML*"){
write-host $group.name + $group.managedby }

}
```

ERROR:
    Get-ADGroup : Identity info provided in the extended attribute: 'ManagedBy' coul
    d not be resolved. Reason: 'Cannot find an object with identity: 'ML*' under: 'D
    C=we,DC=dirsrv,DC=com'.'.

@Paul: here is my error still:

[image]

Comment: `The term 'Get-adgroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` I'd have thought you need to solve this before you worry about any scripting. Doesn't look like it's finding the cmdlet at all.

Comment: I have used get-adgroup for a few programs before so getting that error didn't make much sense to me

Comment: See the problem with what you are trying to do is that the managedby property contains a DistinguishedName, you will have a hard time comparing a DN to something like "ML*". what you could try is `get-aduser ml*` then get the DN of the user and compare it to the managedby property if that helps. Or using your last example add a second asterisk before ML like this `$managed -like "*ML*"` in the loop

Comment: I tried editing my code a little to be like what you said 

    $MLgroupAll = get-adgroup -Properties managedby, enabled,     name     -filter {managedby -eq $name}
    foreach ($group in $MLgroupAll) {

    $managed = Get-AdUser $_.ManagedBy
    if ($managed -like "ML*"){
    write-host $group.name + $group.managedby }

    } "

But I still recieved the same errors as my last example. I also don't want the * before ML because the owner name starts with ML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works for me (orienting myself at your last try):

```
get-adgroup -filter * -Properties managedby | % { 

if($_.managedby -like "CN=ML*"){
write-host $_.name + $_.managedby
}

}
```

Comment: i posted an image using your example. Still had issues

Comment: Oh I see you removed my filter part out. Well I removed that which removed errors... just nothing printed haha

Comment: @AlyssaCooke in that case there is probably no group managed by the user, or is there?

Comment: Ok the CN=ML did work... Ok I see what you did. I will play with it a little more to get just the managed by name versus the whole CN=ML45545, OU=Exchange .... stuff

Comment: Didnt' realize that the CN= part mattered. I've searched name -like "APP*" and worked so figured managedby was no different

Comment: @AlyssaCooke that´s what i thought, like mentioned in my comment on your question it´s a Distinguished Name thats why your approach didn´t work